# Force class construction exclusively inside factory

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

I wanted to know if anyone knows of a way to force a class hierarchy to be constructible only by the factory, effectively prohibiting the direct use of `std::make_shared` outside of that factory.

In the example below I have **Node** as the base class and **SceneNode** as one of the many derived classes. **Node** contains a static member function **create()** which should be the factory and only way to create new instances of **Node**-derived classes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
  public:
    template <class T, class... Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> create(Args&&... args)
    {
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<Node, T>::value, "T must derive from Node");
      std::shared_ptr<T> node = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      return node;
    }

  protected:
    Node() {}

};

class SceneNode : public Node {
  public:
    SceneNode() : Node()
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = Node::create<SceneNode>(); // Should be the only way
    auto b = std::make_shared<SceneNode>(); // Should be forbidden
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. If users are free to write their own classes that are derived from `Node`, then how could you imagine that their construction needs could be met by the `Node::create` function, which they can't change? The design does not make sense to me.

Comment: It's not possible. Derived class must have access to base class constructor, if you want to create an object of derived class. You could use aggregation instead of inheritance, but overall it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Brian, I don't quiet understand the question. Node::create() forwards the arguments to their constructor.

Comment: @Brian This comes up if you need the factory to configure the base portion in a way the constructor can't. For example, it might need to register the resulting `shared_ptr` which isn't available during the constructor. So, even if you can derive from the base class, the derived class would still need to go through the factory's construction process.

Comment: One possibility is to have the base class' constructor require an object of a type that only the factory can provide. Then, the constructors are technically accessible, but ultimately can't be invoked by anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to create a type that only the factory can instantiate, and have an instance of that class be required to construct the base type. You can establish a convention where the first constructor argument for types that derive from `Node` is a value of or reference to that type which is fed to `Node`'s constructor. Since it's not possible for anyone else to have a `NodeKey` users can't instantiate anything that derives from `Node` without going through the factory.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

// Class that can only be instantiated by the factory type
class NodeKey {
private:
    NodeKey() {};
    friend class Factory;
};

class Factory {
public:
    template<class T, class ... Args>
    auto make(Args&&... args) {
        auto ptr = std::make_shared<T>(NodeKey{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // Finish initializing ptr
        return ptr;
    }
};

class Node {
public:
    // Can only be called with an instance of NodeKey
    explicit Node(const NodeKey &) {};
};

class Foo : public Node {
public:
    // Forwards the instance 
    explicit Foo(const NodeKey & key) : Node(key) {};
};

int main()
{
    Factory factory;
    auto f = factory.make<Foo>();
}
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty nice construct! Relies on some convention, but that's OK I guess. Thanks!

Comment: You can make it more foolproof by making the key non-copyable. But you will still be able to create new Foo instances from the Foo constructor where even a reference to temporary will still be valid.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way of making your factory the only class able to instanciate a given class is to make your class constructor private, and making your factory friend of your class:

```
class Foo
{
    friend class FooFactory;

private:
    Foo() = default;
};

class FooFactory
{
public:
    static Foo* CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }
    static void DestroyFoo(Foo* p_toDestroy) { delete p_toDestroy; }
};

int main()
{
    // Foo foo; <== Won't compile
    Foo* foo = FooFactory::CreateFoo();
    FooFactory::DestroyFoo(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT (With some inheritance):**

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
    friend class FooBaseFactory;

protected:
    Foo() = default;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    friend class FooBaseFactory;

protected:
    Bar() = default;
};

class FooBaseFactory
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static T* Create()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value, "T must derive from Foo");
        return new T();
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void Destroy(T* p_toDestroy)
    { 
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value, "T must derive from Foo");
        delete p_toDestroy;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Foo foo; <== Won't compile
    Foo* foo = FooBaseFactory::Create<Foo>();
    FooBaseFactory::Destroy<Foo>(foo);

    // Bar bar; <== Won't compile
    Bar* bar = FooBaseFactory::Create<Bar>();
    FooBaseFactory::Destroy<Bar>(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But now you can't inherit from `Foo`. The goal is to have a factory that constructs derived types and to also prevent the user from instantiating the types without going through the factory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes you can

Comment: Then please show a class derive from `Foo`, be constructed by the factory and failing to be constructed outside of the factory. Edit : If you inherit from `Foo`, the derived class won't be constructible.

Comment: @AdrienGivry, the constructor of the base class is already protected, preventing a direct construction from outside the factory. The problem is that the user can create a derived class with a public constructor and construct that one from outside the factory.

Comment: Side note: A class of nothing but static methods could be a namespace of free functions.

Comment: A drawback with the edited solution is that there is no way for the factory to use `std::make_shared`, if that's desirable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, the drawback with the edited solution is that there is no guarantee that the user will actually make the constructor of ```Bar``` protected.